# Monoid - Commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $M:=(X, \star)$ be a monoid and let $A\neq \emptyset$ be a set. We define a composition $\hat{\star}$ on $X^A$ by $$\hat{\star}:X^A\times X^A\rightarrow X^A , \ (f,g)\mapsto f\hat{\star} g$$ where $f\hat{\star} g\in X^A$ is defined by $$f\hat{\star} g:A\rightarrow X , \ a\mapsto f(a)\star g(a)$$

Show the following:

1. $\hat{M}:=(X^A, \hat{\star})$ is a monoid.
2. $M$ is commutative iff $\hat{M}$ is commutative.
3. Describe the elements $f\in \hat{M}$, that are invertible.

$$$$

**For 1.** do we have to show the existence of an identity element?

**For 2:** We suppose that $M$ is commutative and so we get that $x,y\in X$ then $x\star y=y\star x$. Now we consider elements of $\hat{M}$. Let $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}\in X^A$, so $\tilde{x}(a), \tilde{y}(a)\in X$. So from th commutativity of $M$ we get that $\tilde{x}(a)\star \tilde{y}(a)=\tilde{y}(a)\star \tilde{x}(a)$. Is this correct?

**For 3:** We have to find $g$ such that $f(a)\star g(a)=\text{id}$, or not?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your questions and put the answer to the remainder of the question in spoilers.

1) Yes, having an identity is part of the definition of a monoid.

> Explicitly, if $e \in X$ is the identity of $M$, you can show that the function $f(a) = e$ for all $a \in A$ is the identity of $\widehat{M}$.

2) Your proof of this is correct.

> To prove the converse, consider the map $M \longrightarrow \widehat{M}$ via $x \mapsto \widehat{x}$, which is defined via $\widehat{x}(a) = x$ for all $a \in A$. This is an injective monoid homomorphism (respects multiplication and identity). By commutativity of $\widehat{M}$, $\widehat{x}\widehat{y} = \widehat{y}\widehat{x}$. Hence, $\widehat{yx} = \widehat{xy}$ so by injectivity, $xy = yx$ and $M$ is commutative.

3) Not quite. Having $fg = {\rm id}$ in $\widehat{M}$ says that $f$ has a right inverse and $g$ has a left inverse. However, being invertible in a monoid means that you must have both left and right inverses (and they will coincide in this case). For an explicit example, take some infinite set $S$ and let $M = ({\rm End}(S), \circ)$ where ${\rm End}(S)$ is all the maps $S \longrightarrow S$. Because $S$ is infinite, you can find a injection $f: S \longrightarrow S$ which is not surjective. Hence, we can find some $g: S \longrightarrow S$ such that $g \circ f = {\rm id}_S$ but because $f$ is not surjective we cannot find a right inverse.

> We can therefore see that $f \in \widehat{M}$ is invertible iff $f(a)$ is invertible for all $a \in A$. Concisely, if we let $G \subseteq M$ be the invertible elements (which form a monoid, in fact a group), then this is nothing more than $\widehat{G}$ under your notation.

Comment: **As for 1:** you say that showing that the identity is contained is part of the definition. What else do we have to show so that $\hat{M}$ is a monoid?

Comment: A monoid is a set equipped with a binary operation which is associative and has an identity. You therefore have to show that the $\widehat{*}$ you defined is a binary operation (though this is often clear enough that people don't mention it), that the binary operation satisfies $a(bc) = (ab)c$, and that you have an identity $e$ such that $ea = a = ae$.

Comment: As for the identity, why can we set $f(a)=e$ for each $e$ ?

Comment: Well do you agree that $f(a) = e$ for all $a$ defines a valid element of $X^A$? As for why this is the identity of $\widehat{M}$, let's go by definition. Take an arbitrary $g \in X^A$. Then for all $a \in A$, $f(a) g(a) = e g(a) = g(a)$ and $g(a) f(a) = g(a) e = g(a)$. Hence, for all $g \in X^A$, $fg = g = gf$ so $f$ is the identity of $\widehat{M}$.

Comment: Ok, I see!! Thanks for the explanation!! **As for 3:** $f\in \hat{M}$ is invertible iff $f(a)$ is invertible for all $a\in A$. Could you explain to me further how $\hat{G}$ looks like?

Comment: Sure. I rushed that a bit in my answer. $\widehat G$ is the functions $A \longrightarrow G$ with the same multiplication you defined for $\widehat M$. But every function landing in $G$ can equally well be regarded as landing in $M$. Hence, we view $\widehat G \subseteq \widehat M$ as a submonoid. It is also precisely the invertible elements of $\widehat M$. Indeed, $f$ is invertible iff $f(a)$ is invertible (i.e. in $G$) for all $a$. Hence, $f, is invertible iff $f \in \widehat G$.